# Mostrar columna en última posición con el puglin DataTable

Tags: bootstrap, datatable, diseño

Estoy usando el puglin DataTable junto con BootStrap 4 en modo responsive y me surge la siguiente pregunta:

¿Es posible mostrar una columna determinada siempre en última posición a pesar de reducir o aumentar la pantalla de un navegador?

Tomando el siguiente ejemplo: https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html

Tenemos las siguientes columnas:

```html
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>First name</th>
    <th>Last name</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Office</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Start date</th>
    <th>Salary</th>
    <th>Extn.</th>
    <th>E-mail</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Como podeis observar el campo 'E-mail' se encuentra dentro del desplegable, sin embargo, quisiera que este campo estuviera siempre visible en última posición independientemente de si se reduce la pantalla. Es decir, que se oculten dentro del botón otros campos en su lugar.

Comment: Datatables tiene un plugin que haces lo que necesitas: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/, revisa la documentación y si tienes dudas, vuelve acá y dale en [edit]

Comment: Gracias @JheymanMejia ! Añade esta solución como respuesta para que pueda darte +1

Comment: [Puedes responder tú mismo a tu pregunta, y marcarla como aceptada.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a @JheymanMejia encontré la solución, buscaba la siguiente propiedad:
[Left and right fixed columns](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html)

Integrado con BootStrap: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html